# Which is the best option for make folders from web with AD authentication?

Tags: web, active-directory, directory

I am interested in making a web for a creating a folder structure with acl in a Microsoft AD Domain, the process would be the following:

- The user log in to the web (best with credentials of Windows user)
- Authorized users give the name of the folder (in this case the name of the project)
- A structured folder is created with the correct ACL
- Also I need the option to move the folder to another location and remove/rename the folder

I don't know what is the best option, and more compatible to do this, I'm a bit lost for start googling

Comment: You should use a login (for user) GPO with a .vbs in your AD domain controller to make this.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the problem with the .vbs is the permissions, I don't want to give permissions for all the folder, for example, whit the follow structure:


\\server\share\projects
\\server\share\projects\Project1
\\server\share\projects\Project1\Tech
\\server\share\projects\Project1\Money

I don't want to give permissions for anybody to write in the **projects** folder, and if I make a .vbs for making folders whit acl's I need to give it to the user that executes the code